# Wp Redirect Not Working Can u Help

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, wp-redirect, wp-mail

Hey I developed a form in which user will add detial and it will send email to the team using wp mail. Now i have two issue one is i am having redirect issue i want to redirect user to back page after email sent but it is not working. Other Issue is that I am trying to send product detail with email but i see only email full name and some msg not product detail in the message please check if u can help

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Product Request Form
*/
get_header();
?>

<div class="product-request-form">
    <br>
    <br>
    <h3>Request Price</h3>
    <br>
    <hr>

    <form id="request-form" method="post">
        <div class="form-row">
            <input type="text" name="full-name" id="full-name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" rows="10" required></textarea>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>">
        
        <input type="submit" value="Request Price" name="submit-request">
    </form>

    <?php
        // Check if a product ID is provided in the URL
        $product_id = isset($_GET['product_id']) ? intval($_GET['product_id']) : 0;
        if ($product_id > 0) {
            // Retrieve product information and display it
            $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
            if ($product) {
                echo '<div class="product-details-row">';
                echo '<div class="product-image">' . $product->get_image() . '</div>';
                echo '<br>';
                echo '<div class="product-info">';
                echo '<h3>' . $product->get_name() . '</h3>';
                echo '<p>' . $product->get_description() . '</p>';
                // Add more product details as needed.
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
    ?>
</div>

<style>
    .form-row input[type="text"],.form-row input[type="email"],.form-row textarea {
        width: 100%;
        
    }
    input[type="submit"]{
        margin-left:3px;
        margin-bottom:30px;
        margin-top:20px;
    }

.request
</style>


<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit-request'])) {
    $full_name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['full-name']);
    $email = sanitize_email($_POST['email']);
    $message = sanitize_text_field($_POST['message']);
    $product_id = isset($_POST['product_id']) ? intval($_POST['product_id']) : 0;

    // Send the email to the predefined email address
    $to = 'example@gmail.com'; // Change to your email address
    $subject = 'Product Request';
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

    // Construct the email message
    $email_message = "Full Name: $full_name<br>";
    $email_message .= "Email: $email<br>";
    $email_message .= "Message: $message<br>";

    if ($product_id > 0) {
        $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
        if ($product) {
            $email_message .= "<br>Product Details:<br>";
            $email_message .= "Name: " . $product->get_name() . "<br>";
            $email_message .= "Price: " . wc_price($product->get_price()) . "<br>";
            $email_message .= "Description: " . $product->get_description() . "<br>";
            // Add more product details as needed.
        }
    }
    sleep(2);
    $sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, $email_message, $headers);

    if ($sent) {
        // Redirect to the custom URL after sending the email
        wp_redirect('https://thebrief-sa.com/product/' . sanitize_title($product->get_name()) . '/');
        exit();
    } else {
        echo '<p class="error-message">There was an error sending your request. Please try again later.</p>';
    }
}


get_footer();
?>
```

u can add Your Email to test
here is the function i am using on onTap of a button

```
function custom_request_price_button() {
global $product;

if ($product->get_price() == 0) {
    $product_id = $product->get_id();
    $request_form_page_url = 'https://thebrief-sa.com/product-request-form/?product_id=' . $product_id;
    
    return '<a class="request-price-button" style="background-color: black; color: white; padding:10px" href="' . esc_url($request_form_page_url) . '">Request Price</a>';
}

return '';
}
add_shortcode('request_price_button', 'custom_request_price_button');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`wp_redirect()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) uses PHP's [`header()`](https://php.net/header) function to redirect. Headers *cannot* be sent after anything has been displayed by the browser. If you want this to all be done in a single file, you'll need to do the redirection *before* anything has been sent to the browser.

Comment: so does there is any other way we can redirect user to other location please i don't understand much php this is all done by AI

Comment: The advice I'd give is to move the `$_POST` check and the `wp_redirect()` call to the top of the code, before anything is outputted. Make sure you `exit;` after the redirect (it looks like the AI got that right, at least). Beyond that I'm not willing to debug AI code; you might need to contact a WordPress developer for assistance.

Comment: ok i will try this may be it will resolve the issue

Comment: Thank its working now after taking all the product code before header